# Get some words from a string until there is a vast pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the columns is a string. I only want the first words from that column that are in front of a date (also in string form).
The problem is that I don't know how much words there are in front of the date.

The string rows of the column looks like the following:

```
word1 word2 word3 02/08/2022 XXX XXX XXX
word1 04/09/2019 XXX XXX XXX
word1 word2 word3 word4 10/12/2021 XXX XXX XXX
word1 word2 30/11/2022 XXX XXX XXX
```

So I want only:

```
word1 word2 word3
word1
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2
```

The 'XXX' stands for words of which I do not know in advance how many there are.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Series.str.split` with a regex pattern

```
s = pd.Series(["word1 word2 word3 02/08/2022 XXX XXX XXX", "word1 04/09/2019 XXX XXX XXX"])

s.str.split("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}").str[0]

0    word1 word2 word3 
1                word1 
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

example_string = 'word1 word2 word3 02/08/2022 XXX XXX XXX'
match = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',example_string)

desired_string = example_string.split(match.group(1))[0]

output: word1 word2 word3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract`, this avoids parsing the rest of the string and will stop as soon as the date is reached:

```
df['words'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', expand=False)
```

output:

```
                                              col                     word
0        word1 word2 word3 02/08/2022 XXX XXX XXX        word1 word2 word3
1                    word1 04/09/2019 XXX XXX XXX                    word1
2  word1 word2 word3 word4 10/12/2021 XXX XXX XXX  word1 word2 word3 word4
3              word1 word2 30/11/2022 XXX XXX XXX              word1 word2
```